# Why would you use a LIFO stack over an array?

Tags: arrays, performance, stack, time-complexity

I was recently in an interview that required me to choose over the two data structures for a problem, and now I have the question of:

What is the reasoning for using a `Stack` over an `array` if the only operations needed are `push` and `pop`? An `array` provides constant time for appending and popping the last element from it and it takes up generally less memory than implementing a `Stack` with a `LinkedList`. It also provides random access should it be required. Is the only reasoning because an `array` is typically of fixed size, so we need to dynamically resize the array for each element we put in? This still is in constant time though isn't it unless the penalty is disproportionate?

Comment: Arrays are contiguous structure , they are allocated in a continuous manner. What if you needed about a million of float type? You cant possibly get it allocated always dynamically. So you can go for linked type of data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects to consider here...

First, a *Stack* is an abstract data type. It doesn't define how to implement itself.

An *array* is (generally) a well defined concrete implementation, and might even be fixed size unless explicitly defined to be dynamic.

A dynamic array can be implemented such that it automatically grows by some factor when exhausted and also might shrink when fill rate drops. These operations are **not constant time**, but are actually **amortized to constant time** because the array *doesn't* grow or shrink in each operation. In terms of memory usage it's hard to imagine an array being more expensive then a linked list unless extremely under used.

The main problem with an array is large allocation size. This is both a problem of maximum limitation and memory fragmentation. Using a linked list avoids both issues because every entry has a small memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

In some languages like C++, the underlying container that the 'stack' class uses can actually be changed between a dynamic array (vector), linked list (list), or even a double ended queue (deque). I only mention this because its typically not fair to compare a stack vs an array (one is an interface, another is a data structure).

Most dynamic array implementations will allocate more space than is needed, and upon filling the array they will again resize to 2x the size and so on. This avoids allocations and keeps the performance of push generally constant time. However the occasional resize does require copying elements O(n), though this is usually said to amortized to constant time. So in general, you are correct in that this is efficient.

Linked lists on the other hand typically require allocations for every push, which can be somewhat expensive, and the node's they create are larger in size than a single element in the array.

One possible advantage of linked lists, however, is that they do not require contiguous memory. If you have many many elements, its possible that you can fail to allocate a large enough block of memory for an array. Having said that, linked lists take up more memory... so its a bit of a wash.

In C++ for example, the stack by default uses the deque container. The deque is typically implemented as a dynamic array of 'pages' of memory. Each page of memory is fixed in size, which allows the container to actually have random access properties. Moreover, since each page is separate, then the entire container does not require contiguous memory meaning that it can store many many elements. Resizing is also cheap for a deque because it simply allocates another page, making it a great choice for a large stack.